# CORS with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: drupal-7, cors

I'm trying to make a POST request between two sites.

I've seen the need to change header of request on server side using the access-allow. My problem is that when I send request I can't see this modification in the response header.

If I go on directly on page the headers are change. If I sent request with GET, I can see too that the headers has been changed. Maybe there is server configuration of http which is forbidden across domain POST request?

I'm using a Ngnix server that serves Drupal sites.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the header you should change is the response header of the site that receive the request (or site 2). Thus, it allows the client (or site 1) to perform a CORS request, adding the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" and the domain of site 1 (or '*') into the response.