# XMLHttpRequest cannot load URL. Origin not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cors

I want to make a small website that uses xml data from another domain. (Weather data from Weather Underground: www.wunderground.com). I am using just html and javascript, and writing it all in Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web.

I make and send the xml request as follows:

```
url = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/3c6e3d838e217361/geolookup/conditions/forecast/q/51.11999893,-114.01999664.xml";

xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
```

The problem is that I get the following error in the Google Chrome (version 29.0.1547.66) developer console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.wunderground.com/api/3c6e3d838e217361/geolookup/conditions/forecast/q/51.11999893,-114.01999664.xml. Origin http://localhost:49933 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Or this on Internet Explorer (version 10.0.8) console:

```
SEC7118: XMLHttpRequest for http://api.wunderground.com/api/3c6e3d838e217361/geolookup/conditions/forecast/q/51.11999893,-114.01999664.xml required Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).
```

As I understand it, CORS (http://enable-cors.org/) needs effort by both the client and the server to work. I want to assume that the Weather Underground API knows what it is doing and has enabled things appropriately, such as setting the response header to include 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *', and I know that I get the same problems when I try the same code using another API provider (World Weather Online). So I think this is something I should be able to fix in my client code. 
Another SO answer where the suggestion is to fix the server-side header:
[CORS with XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14728418/cors-with-xmlhttprequest)

I have tried to find answers, but don't understand articles such as:
http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/dom-access-control-using-cross-origin-resource-sharing/
http://saltybeagle.com/2009/09/cross-origin-resource-sharing-demo/

Comment: Did you check the headers they set?

Comment: I directly open your url in Chrome and developer tools tell me that no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is returned.

Comment: Rule 1 of development: don't assume other people have done things to make your life easier. Look at their API docs. JSON, XML and JSONP - with examples. No mention of CORS. Use JSONP.

Comment: @Passerby Thanks, I didn't know you could do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) with JSONP if you want in jquery

For javascript see here , http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html and http://www.leggetter.co.uk/2010/03/12/making-cross-domain-javascript-requests-using-xmlhttprequest-or-xdomainrequest.html

Use **.json** format data rather than **.xml** to make your application simpler and faster i.e http://api.wunderground.com/api/3c6e3d838e217361/geolookup/conditions/forecast/q/51.11999893,-114.01999664.json

Comment: My response is not jsonp, it's json..what can i do??

Comment: @SweetWisherツ Whatever it is , if you send a request to a cross domain , you response should be of type jsonp

Comment: My response in in JSON not in JSONP

Comment: @SweetWisherツ Just try it