# AngularJS Cross-Domain POST request blocked by CORS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cors

I am working on an app that uses an API from a different domain that I have no control over it's header.

The API allows to post to it's api by passing it a username and a key in the url. The method needs to be post and the code would like something like this.

```
$http({
url : url,
method : "POST",
headers : {
     'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
 },
 data : {
     name: "joe", number: 1234567890
 }
}).success(function(data) {
   //do something
});
```

the data being posted is being pass as an object like above.

I'm new to CORS but I have a conceptual idea. Again I have to access to the API. The instructions say that I need to send a post request and pass in a header of the content type          'Content-Type' : 'application/json'

Any help is welcomed, I have looked at post that change angular's settings in the config method

```
$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
```

But it doesn't do anything. I believe this was a fix to an older version of Angular. Other solutions require access to the server which I don't have. The header response looks something like this

```
Allow   GET,PUT,POST,PATCH,HEAD,OPTIONS
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
Date    Wed, 15 Oct 2014 06:42:43 GMT
P3P policyref="https://www.somedomaincom/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="NON DSP COR CURa ADMa DEVa PSAa PSDa IVAa IVDa CONa TELa OUR STP PHY ONL COM NAV INT DEM CNT PRE"
Server  nginx/1.1.19
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Vary    Host, Cookie
```

Comment: below links can be helpful :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18733104/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-url-origin-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origi

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823010/how-to-enable-cors-in-angularjs